# Root changing a user password precludes the user from logging in

Tags: password

When root changes a user password, the user cannot log in.  The fix process is after changing the password, root becomes the user and then changes the password again.  The user can then log in.  Is there something amiss in the config files where root is not trusted?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the specific sequence of commands issued by `root`, and the specific error messages encountered by the user.

Comment: This sounds like the way the `RedHat IDM` handles password resets.  (it's based on `FreeIPA`, which imitates `Active Directory` in some ways)  When a user's password is reset, the user must use the reset password to change to another password.  After that, the other password is honored until the password policy expires it (usually 90+ days later).  The reason for this is `IDM/FreeIPA/AD` authenticates other services as well as Linux login sessions, and the admin trusted with root on Linux servers is not necessarily trusted in the other services.